# Merging mutliple PySpark DataFrames with MergeSchema

Tags: python, pyspark

i want to merge multiple PySpark Dataframes into one PySpark Dataframe.
They all are from the same schema, however they can differ by sometimes missing some of the columns (e.g. Schema contains in general 200 columns with defined data types, from which dataFrame A has 120 columns and dataFrame B has 60 columns).

Is it possible to merge the schema without write and read all dataframes with use of mergeSchema again?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try out the below solution? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to retain the missing columns, you can try this out:

```
# Test dataset
tst1=sqlContext.createDataFrame([1,2],"int").toDF('col1')
tst2=sqlContext.createDataFrame([3,4],"int").toDF('col2')
tst3=sqlContext.createDataFrame([9,10],"int").toDF('col5')
# Master column list, from your schema
col_list=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
# Create an array of dataframes, if you already have it in this format, great :-)
df_arr=[tst1,tst2,tst3]
# For each df, calculate the missing columns
df_arr_miscol = map(lambda x:list(set(col_list)-set(x.columns)),df_arr)
# For each dataframe , create the missing column with null value
df_res=map(lambda x,y:reduce(lambda df,col:df.withColumn(col,F.lit(None)),y,x),df_arr,df_arr_miscol)
#align the columns in all the df so that you can union it, since union function depends on column order
df_col_align = map(lambda x: x.select(col_list),df_res)
#Merge all the dataframes
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
df_final=reduce(DataFrame.union,df_col_align)
df_final.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|null|null|null|null|
|   2|null|null|null|null|
|null|   3|null|null|null|
|null|   4|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|null|   9|
|null|null|null|null|  10|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

If you prefer avoiding the reduce method, or want to try alternatives refer here :
https://medium.com/@mrpowers/performing-operations-on-multiple-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-36e97896c378
It's a great read!